# How to add more context into panick_info when catching?

Tags: rust, panic

In my project I have a panic hook which sends an HTTP request reporting an issue when some unplanned unwrap occurs. I am executing some function 100 times and I would like to somehow know when the panic occurs which of the executions it was in case the panic happened inside the function. Is it possible to somehow add a string to an intercepted unrolling of panic_info or how do people handle this?

I was thinking something along the lines of using catch_unwind, modifying the caught err and resuming the unwind, but the err is of opaque type so I don't see a way to add something to it. I see that panic_info has payload, is it somehow possible to add to it?

I would like to avoid having some global mutex which I can then modify when catching the unwind

Comment: Do you want a backtrace?

Answer (score 1):

One simple option is to just use `expect()` instead of `unwrap()` and use an informative error message.

Another way is to use a custom panic type and try to downcast it, e.g.:

```rust
use std::any::Any;
use std::panic::{self, panic_any, UnwindSafe};

// The custom panic payload.
// Must be `'static + Any + Send` for `panic_any()`.
pub struct MyPanicInfo {
    pub description: String,
}

trait OptionExt {
    type Inner;
    fn unwrap_with<F: FnOnce() -> MyPanicInfo>(self, f: F) -> Self::Inner;
}
impl<T> OptionExt for Option<T> {
    type Inner = T;
    fn unwrap_with<F: FnOnce() -> MyPanicInfo>(self, f: F) -> Self::Inner {
        match self {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => panic_any(f()),
        }
    }
}

trait ResultExt {
    type Ok;
    type Err;
    fn unwrap_with<F: FnOnce(Self::Err) -> MyPanicInfo>(self, f: F) -> Self::Ok;
}
impl<T, E> ResultExt for Result<T, E> {
    type Ok = T;
    type Err = E;
    fn unwrap_with<F: FnOnce(<Self as ResultExt>::Err) -> MyPanicInfo>(
        self,
        f: F,
    ) -> <Self as ResultExt>::Ok {
        match self {
            Ok(v) => v,
            Err(e) => panic_any(f(e)),
        }
    }
}

pub enum PanicPayload {
    MyPanicInfo(Box<MyPanicInfo>),
    Unknown(Box<dyn Any + Send>),
}
pub fn my_catch_unwind<F: FnOnce() -> R + UnwindSafe, R>(f: F) -> Result<R, PanicPayload> {
    panic::catch_unwind(f).map_err(|payload| match payload.downcast() {
        Ok(my_panic_info) => PanicPayload::MyPanicInfo(my_panic_info),
        Err(unknown_payload) => PanicPayload::Unknown(unknown_payload),
    })
}
```

Then use something like `option.unwrap_with(|| MyPanicInfo { description: "abc".to_owned() })`.

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is having to change the existing code. There are already so many unwraps and expects and I do not want to have to add this string to each of them or change from "unwrap" to some other call in all the invocations. I'm trying to add this string in a centralized manner

Comment: @ditoslav How will you then differentiate between them? You can use a backtrace and find the position in the source code, but you cannot expect the compiler to automagically know the reason it failed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::panic::PanicInfo::location`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/struct.PanicInfo.html#method.location) to get the file, line number, and column of the panic.

Comment: This won't really help to know which specific function execution the panic happened in, which is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Sven I believe best described what I want